# Javascript only addEventListener to parent style both parent and child differently

Tags: javascript, html, css

Currently have a div that controls the width of an element as well as the background color. That div has a child div which has the content which is semi-transparent. Which is why I need the first div. So the background is solid.

Now, I added an event listener to the parent which expands the width of one and decreases the width of the other 2 so they all fit. However, when I click on the parent div I would like the child of that specific div to add a class and remove a class from the other 2. Which I can't seem to figure out. Here's the code. Sorry if my formatting is poor, first time posting on stack overflow and I've googled and searched everything for an answer and can't seem to find one.

```js
var purchaseStepCont = document.querySelectorAll(".step-container");
var purchaseStep = document.querySelectorAll(".step");

for (var i = 0; i < purchaseStepCont.length; i++) {
  purchaseStepCont[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < purchaseStepCont.length; i++) {
      purchaseStepCont[i].classList.remove("stepContActive");
      purchaseStepCont[i].classList.add("stepContDeactive");
      this.classList.add("stepContActive");
      this.classList.remove("stepContDeactive");
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="step-container">
  <div class="step">
    <h1>01.</h1>
    <h3>words</h3>
    <p>wods</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="step-container">
  <div class="step">
    <h1>01.</h1>
    <h3>words</h3>
    <p>wods</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="step-container">
  <div class="step">
    <h1>01.</h1>
    <h3>words</h3>
    <p>wods</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When you were asking your question, there was a big orange **How to Format** box to the right of the text area with useful information in it. There was also an entire toolbar of formatting aids. And a **[?]** button giving formatting help. *And* a preview area located between the text area and the Post Your Question button (so that you'd have to scroll past it to find the button, to encourage you to look at it) showing what your post would look like when posted. Making your post clear, and demonstrating that you took the time to do so, improves your chances of getting good answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're very close. But if you want to add the class to the `.step`, you need `this.firstElementChild.classList.add(...)` rather than `this.classList.add(...)` (since `this` will be the `.step-container`, not the `.step`; but the `.step` is its first element child). Or for more markup flexibility, you could use `this.querySelector(".step")`.

You can also use just a single event handler function rather than recreating it in the loop:

```js
var purchaseStepCont = document.querySelectorAll(".step-container");
var purchaseStep = document.querySelectorAll(".step");
function clickHandler() {
  var thisStep = this.firstElementChild; // Or this.querySelector(".step") would be more flexible
  for (var i = 0; i < purchaseStep.length; i++) {
    if (purchaseStep[i] === thisStep) {
      purchaseStep[i].classList.add("stepContActive");
      purchaseStep[i].classList.remove("stepContDeactive");
    } else {
      purchaseStep[i].classList.remove("stepContActive");
      purchaseStep[i].classList.add("stepContDeactive");
    }
  }
}

for (var i = 0; i < purchaseStepCont.length; i++) {
  purchaseStepCont[i].addEventListener("click", clickHandler);
}
```

```css
.stepContActive {
  color: blue;
}
.stepContDeactive {
  color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div class="step-container">
  <div class="step">
    <h1>01.</h1>
    <h3>words</h3>
    <p>wods</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="step-container">
  <div class="step">
    <h1>01.</h1>
    <h3>words</h3>
    <p>wods</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="step-container">
  <div class="step">
    <h1>01.</h1>
    <h3>words</h3>
    <p>wods</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

`clickHandler` could be a bit shorter if you don't need to support IE11:

```
function clickHandler() {
  var thisStep = this.firstElementChild; // Or this.querySelector(".step") would be more flexible
  for (var i = 0; i < purchaseStep.length; i++) {
    purchaseStep[i].classList.toggle("stepContActive", purchaseStep[i] === thisStep);
    purchaseStep[i].classList.toggle("stepContDeactive", purchaseStep[i] !== thisStep);
  }
}
```

But IE11 doesn't support the second argument to `classList.toggle`.